# C# - is it possible to reset `SerialPort.IsOpen` to `false`?

Tags: c#, usb

I have defined `private SerialPort SP_A = new SerialPort();`

I know `SerialPort.IsOpen` is read only, 
and `SerialPort.Close()` could make `SerialPort.IsOpen = false`

But my problem is:

Before I call `SerialPort.Close()`, serial port(USB) has been plugged out.
After that, I can't call `SerialPort.Close()`
and `SP_A.IsOpen` is still `true` 
so `SP_A` become unusable.

Could I do anything if this problem (plug out) is unavoidable?

**[Update]:**
I have tried

```
try
{
    SP_A.Close();
}
catch
{
    //...
}
```

it successfully makes `.IsOpen = false.`
but it cause `system.objectDisposedException`
and i don't know what it happened.
Because it won't cause this problem in debugger mode.

Comment: I would start by trying to detect device removal via WMI and if device removal is detected skip the .Close() and go right for .Dispose()

Comment: Drivers that emulate a serial port are rarely resilient to surprise removal, they make the port disappear even though you have it opened.  **Always** use the "Safely remove hardware" tray icon, it is there for a good reason.  You found that reason.  And just in general keep your fingers off a USB connector while your program is running, jerking it never once solved a problem.

Comment: Are you sure that calling SerialPort.Close() (and catching any exceptions it throws) won't reset IsOpen back to false?

Comment: I disagree with Hans Passant.  It was always OK to unplug USB-serial devices as long as you later closed all programs that had a handle open to the serial port before plugging the device back in.  Since usbser.sys was rewritten in Windows 10, I think it has gotten even better, and it's OK if you close the old handles after the device is re-plugged but before trying to open the port in other software.

Comment: Thanks Andy P and David Grayson so much.
I have tried two ways you suggested and it works !

Thanks Hans Passant and David Grayson.
Now I know it is not a safety way to unplug USB while the program is running. And I will keep it in mind !

Thank you again for help.

Comment: Well , I ran into a problem again. :-(
i update in this post